# Confusion on sensor resolution specification

Tags: sensor

[This](http://www.crlsensors.com/prodDocs/sa-120r.pdf) sensor has resolution +0.001% F.R. , and output noise of Output Noise 0.02% F.R.

If full range is 10V, according to the datasheet the resolution becomes 0.1mV and the output noise becomes 2mV.

Neglect the accuracy and any other noise sources, does that mean that the output noise already lowering the resolution from 0.1mV to 2mV? If so, what is the point to mention the resolution lower as in the datasheet?

Comment: Are you finished with this question now?

Comment: Yes I forgot to select the answer, thanks for reminding and the nice answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *If so, what is the point to mention the resolution lower as in the
> datasheet?*

The resolution remains the resolution no matter what the noise is. You can always average the signal to remove a lot of noise and "return" to the original resolution (or have signals that appear to have the 0.001% FR resolution).

Comment: Is that because the average of the random noise is zero?

Comment: Usually the case @cm64

Comment: I thought SNR is related to the rms value of the noise not the average. So in this case I want to specify the ideal SNR(neglecting any other external noise sources and uncertainty). In this case I should use the rms value of the given 2mV noise correct(if no averaging used)? I want to specify down to what g this sensor can sense ideally. LP filter would only lower it but not remove. So are you saying SNR can be improved by averaging like applying moving average? So SNR in this case depends on whether we do averaging at the receiving side. I hope I understood you correct. Just to be sure..

Comment: I believe that the 2 mV is a peak-to-peak value and, if it's gaussian white noise (they don't say it seems) then the RMS will be about one-sixth of this. This is all to do with standard deviations and math. Averaging noise reduces its amplitude whilst preserving a slow moving wanted signal.